# Collective nouns for the years of the first and the second decades of a century

Tags: word-request

Provided that the years within a decade starting from the third can be collectively referred to by using the –ies ending (the twenties, the fifties, etc.), what would be the collective nouns for the years of the first and second decades? For the first one, all I could find was "the noughties"; although I'm not sure it's commonly used by native English-speakers.

Comment: We do hear "the teens" for the second decade.  But (this time) there was no agreed short term for the first decade, such as "the naughties".

Comment: I've also heard people say "the nineteen tens" to refer to dates from 1910, to 1919.

Comment: The aughts, is also out there.

Comment: A future question (as yet unanswerable) is will the 2020s be known as the "twenties" (creating an ambiguity with the 1920s) It seems that the first decade be named like this was the "gay 90s" = 1890s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common term I've heard is the *two-thousands* (as compared to the *twenty-tens*).   Individually you can refer to the years as *oh-one, oh-two*, etc.

The *aughts* is another term in infrequent use.  Individual years are *aught-one, aught-two*, etc.

All the other names (like The *Naughties*), while clever, never really caught on.

Answer (score 2):

There are no standard terms.

The "Noughties" has been used, but often in a slightly jokey way (it sounds like the "Naughties"), and I've heard the "teens" used for the second decade. Neither is very standard.

In the UK, the first decade of last Century came to be known as the the "Edwardian" period, as it coincided with the reign of King Edward. One could also say "In the nineteen-hundreds" The second decade was so dominated by the Great War, that there isn't a clear culture associated with the decade. We would just say "during world war 1". In the nineteen tens would be possible for this decade (but not the "tens")

Given these options the clearest words to use would be "In the first decade of the twenty-first century" or "in the second decade....". An alternative could be "In the twenty-hundreds" and "In the twenty-tens", but neither is common.

Comment: I fear it will in future be known as the "pre-Brexit period", or worse: "the pre-War period"...